# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when synthesizing @property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references, iboutlet

I'm a newbie to ObjC/Cocoa and Mac development in general, and toying with the basics.

The simplistic default template for a new Cocoa application in Xcode 4.2 on Lion looks like this:

```
// AppDelegate.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end



// Appdelegate.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

@end
```

I've been using that as a basis for various experiments. Reading up on Automatic Reference Counting (which the project is set to use)—[this article](http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/09/07/objc-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-explained/), for example—I assumed that one could, perhaps even *should* replace the `assign` qualifier for `NSWindow *window` with `weak`, but that does not seem to be the case.

The app builds fine, but hangs during startup, with `Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION"` in `AppDelegate.m` on the line with `@synthesize window = _window;`.

Changing the qualifier to `strong` makes the program work, but I fail to see how it would make sense to go from `assign` to `strong`. I'd gotten the impression that the pairings for non-ARC/ARC are assign/weak and retain/strong.

A more experienced coder friend suggested that even if the `weak` qualifier causes `window` to be prematurely deallocated and some access attempt on it to fail, the exception should be `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, not `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`.

I'm obviously missing something here, but I have no idea what.

**EDIT:** After a closer look at the crash-time gdb output, the same friend pointed me to [this article by Mike Ash](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html) that sheds some light on this. Due to reasons beyond my understanding, `NSWindow` and some other classes that override `retain` and `release` can't be the target of zeroing weak references. Interestingly, changing the property declaration to this works:

`@property (unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;`

...even though `unsafe_unretained` isn't mentioned in [Apple's documentation for Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html).

With that, a **REVISED QUESTION:**

What would be the proper way to go here? Stick to `assign` despite mentions around the web that it shouldn't be used with ARC? Go for `strong`? Keep using `unsafe_unretained` since it seems to work? Something else?

Comment: Wow, three answers, two with the same link that I edited my own question with while I was editing... Anyway, the bottom paragraph in the revised question still stands. Authoritative references appreciated :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Conceptually, 'weak' is the correct qualifier for a top-level IBOutlet on OS X (iOS is another story). However, to create a proper weak reference that zeroes on deallocation requires cooperation from the Objective C runtime. Classes that override retain or release break this support and so you can't create a weak reference to them. UIWindow is one such class.

That's why the template uses 'assign'. Perhaps it should really use the synonym 'unsafe_unretained' if ARC is enabled. In either case you have a simple weak reference that is not zeroed.

Comment: 'unsafe_unretained' is a synonym for 'assign'? Not to question your expertise, but [citation needed] :-). If for no other reason, then just to further my understanding of the topic.

Comment: [http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property) I'm using 'synonym' in the sense that both imply __unsafe_unretained when used in a property declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Mike Ash's blog discusses the issue with some Cocoa classes.

Look for it in the middle part of the page:  [Friday Q&A ARC](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html).  Look/Search for the text that starts with "ARC's implementation of zeroing weak references..."

The problem is that some classes don't handle the zeroing weak references that __weak brings.  The solution is to go with what the normal ARC templates provide *assign*.

Well, to answer the second question, even Apple's templates use assign for window when using ARC.  So you may be safe for now.  But your mileage may vary in the future.

Answer (score 2):

[Mike Ash has a very good explanation of what's going wrong here](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html) (search for "ARC's implementation"). The gist of it is that the NSWindow class *specifically* does not support weak referencing: apparently because it relies on overriding retain and release with its own implementations.

I expect there's a few more such gotchas scattered through the legacy Cocoa classes, and these don't appear to be documented yet - instead, you find out through a runtime error. (I expect this will become a compiler warning as well at some point.)